# Exporting feature colors from categorized polygon layer to Excel diagram using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have an xxx.shp layer with polygones which is categorized and colored according to the names of management companies. I need to make a circle diagram for this layer in Excel. Is it possible to make this by any plugin?

[image: my project]

Comment: What do you need to make a "circle diagram" in Excel? A sheet with what values in? Without delving into Python code, you can copy/paste the style as an XML document, then edit that into a CSV of {label, red, green, blue} lines to load into Excel, but that would be tedious to edit by hand for lots of categories, but easier with a programming language. Can you program in Python? I don't see a plugin that would do it.

Comment: @Spacedman, I'm new to Python. May be that's just a good case to expand my knowledge)) Do you know some special libraries, that could be useful for my goal?

Comment: You could do this in QGIS' Python, using the QGIS functions to get the layer, then get the *renderer*, then loop over the categories and output what you need. If I get a chance to write a full answer I will, but I still need the format you need for your "circle diagrams".

Comment: I want to get a pie-diagram (example - https://www.edrawsoft.com/pie-diagram.php) with percentages for each company.

Comment: I don't know how to do that in Excel. What rows and columns do you need to do that? Where do the colours come from?

Comment: Currently I'm using Excel to make such kind of a diagram. Of course I can copy all RGB in a manual way, but usually that take too much time. I'm ready to use any other free soft except Excel. In the layer there are features with the living area (let it be column No 1) and management company (column No 2) indicated for each house. I want to get the pie-diagramm showing how much living area (in percentages) each company manage in this town. Thank you for your help )

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starter on getting categorical renderer info out of a layer.

Use the python console. First get the map canvas:

```
mc = iface.mapCanvas()
```

Next get the layer you want. It must be visible on the map canvas. Here I'm getting the first layer, layer 0 (python starts counting at zero). Get whichever layer you need by its number:

```
l = mc.layers()[0]
l.name()
u'CCG_April_2017_Ultra_Gen_Clipped_England_V4'
```

I use `layer.name()` to get the layer name to check I have the right layer.

Next I get the layer's *renderer*, which is the object that controls its appearance:

```
r = l.rendererV2()
```

Then loop over the renderer's categories, printing out the category label and the three components of the color, red, green, and blue:

```
for rr in r.categories():
  print rr.label(),",", rr.symbol().color().red(),",", rr.symbol().color().green(),",", rr.symbol().color().blue()
```

This produces:

```
NHS A , 146 , 116 , 202
NHS B , 69 , 102 , 222
[etc]
NHS V , 239 , 119 , 213
NHS W , 201 , 17 , 214
 , 230 , 72 , 60
```

Note the last line is for the "none of the above" category.

This comma-separated data can be cut and pasted into a spreadsheet.

Things you might want to change:

- output the colour in a different format, eg a hex code like `#F08080`
- send the output straight to a file - read up on Python's I/O functions

Things that might go wrong:

- QGIS's symbols can be very complex and the above only works for the simplest filled point marker symbols. If you have different shapes and symbol layers and outlines and shading and whatever, this will probably break.

Comment: OK. I'll try to follow your recomendations. Thank you very much!